# Swift - What does ... mean in a function parameter?

Tags: swift

What does the ... syntax mean in function parameters

For example

```
func setupViews(views: UIView...) {
  ...
}
```

I saw this in some tutorial recently and as far as I understand its just an array of UIViews.

So is it the same as writing

```
func setupViews(views: [UIView]) {
   ...
}
```

or is there a difference?

Comment: Open https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html and scroll down to "variadic parameters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents a Variadic Paramater, from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html):

> A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type.
>   You use a variadic parameter to specify that the parameter can be
>   passed a varying number of input values when the function is called.
>   Write variadic parameters by inserting three period characters (`...`)
>   after the parameter’s type name.
>
> The values passed to a variadic parameter are made available within
>   the function’s body as an array of the appropriate type. For example,
>   a variadic parameter with a name of numbers and a type of `Double...`
>   is made available within the function’s body as a constant array
>   called numbers of type `[Double]`.
>
> The example below calculates the arithmetic mean (also known as the
>   average) for a list of numbers of any length:
>
> ```
> func arithmeticMean(numbers: Double...) -> Double {
>     var total: Double = 0
>     for number in numbers {
>         total += number
>     }
>     return total / Double(numbers.count)
> }
> arithmeticMean(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
> // returns 3.0, which is the arithmetic mean of these five numbers
> arithmeticMean(3, 8.25, 18.75)
> // returns 10.0, which is the arithmetic mean of these three numbers
> ```

You can only have one Variadic Param per function.

As you can see, there is a subtle difference between an input paramater of `[Double]` and `Double...`

**When using a function with a Variadic parameter you don't need to pass the objects/values as an array.**

Food for thought; How would you call this method? `func arithmeticMean(numbers: [Double]...) -> Double`

Like so:

```
arithmeticMean([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) // you could keep adding more and more arrays here if desired.
```

In this example 'numbers' would be an array of double arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much. Must have missed this part in the documentation. Its not something I see a lot so I just wondered what it was.

Comment: @crashoverride777, my pleasure.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer as well, those last few sentences helped me understand it properly. I will mark it in a few minutes.

Comment: @crashoverride777 - you're very welcome.